# How to install emacs code browser on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, emacs

I'm getting started using emacs. I would like to set up the emacs code browser. How do I do this? I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx.

Answer (score 2):

It's [a package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ecb) in universe.  You can install it with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ecb
```

If you need to enable universe, [see here](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-enable-universe-and-multiverse-repositories-on-ubuntu).

Comment: Cool, thanks...what next? I ran the command. It seemed to install some stuff. Now how do I "activate" it?

Comment: also...is the period after ecb is a typo?

Comment: In emacs, run `ecb-activate`.  The period was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Download ECB from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecb/) .there's just one easy to install dependancy which is CEDET (= Collection of Emacs Development Environment Tools)

get [cedet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cedet/files/cedet/1.0pre6/cedet-1.0pre6.tar.gz/download), unpack it (I'm working in ~/src) and build it with `make`

add settings in your .emacs

get ecb, unpack it
add settings in your .emacs

add to load-path and (require 'ecb)
restart emacs

you may be prompted to confirm some initialization actions
in emacs: tools -> Start Code Browser ECB

Comment: what settings do I add to my .emacs file?

Comment: http://gaoithe.blogspot.com/2009/07/ecb-emacs-code-browser-quick-to-set-up.html

Answer (score 1):

I wish to advise against using the Debian Universe package *right now*. It contains the severely outdated 2.32 version. You really want to start with a 2.40+ version.